# I have switchable graphics AMD R7 M265 but the "strong" GPU never gets used, how can I force it?

Tags: ati, radeon

Ubuntu discovers both of the adapters (*=default):

```
 aticonfig --list-adapters
* 0. 00:01.0 AMD Radeon(TM) R5 Graphics       
  1. 01:00.0 AMD Radeon R7 M265 Series
```

However, in CCC it shows "graphics adapter" as the R5:

[active adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bx8G.png)

The driver selection I have is:

[see picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUbFu.png)

xserver-xorg-video-ati (recommended)
Version: 1:7:3.0-1ubuntu3.1

fglrx-updates
Version: 2:15.200-0ubuntu0.5

fglrx 
Version: 2:15.200-0ubuntu0.5

And I have the high performance options elected:

[high performance][3]

Everything feels slow and crappy on linux because I can't select the proper driver. I've searched all across Google and found people with different success in different things, but mostly people just failing.

So what's going on? Anyone else have this switchable graphics crap that doesn't work on Ubuntu? My computer can barely load a stock chart and playing Counterstrike is hopeless because my framerate is such crap.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue: my laptop has an integrated Intel Graphic and a dedicated R7 M265.

Enabling fglrx drivers results just in an evident performance loss. I've also tried to install latest drivers directly from ATI website: things are a little bit better but still far from what I consider "acceptable". Actually I'm just using my integrated card, a solution that really don't like...